# IOS - Dependency issue when pod install

Tags: ios, dependencies, cocoapods

I'm not an iOS dev but I'm in charge of compiling a new build of an iOS app but when I'm launching the command `pod install`. Pod generates an error like that.

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `XMLDictionary (= 1.4.0)` required by `Podfile.lock`
- `XMLDictionary (~> 1.4.0)` required by `AWSCore (2.1.2)`

I try to edit directly the Podfile.lock by changing `XMLDictionnary` version by `(~> 1.4.0)` but, obviously it does not work. Can someone help me to solve that dependency errors ?

Many thanks in advance.

[EDIT] As recommanded in comments. I already done the `pod update` command.

But it return me the following error.

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `XMLDictionary (~> 1.4.0)` required by `AWSCore (2.1.2)`

Comment: may be `pod update` will help

Comment: Already done. Got this.

[!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:

- `XMLDictionary (~> 1.4.0)` required by `AWSCore (2.1.2)`